# count occurances of each word in apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
  val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "wc")

  val lines: RDD[String] = sc.textFile("/tmp/inputs/*")
  val errors = lines.filter(line => line.contains("ERROR"))

  // Count all the errors
  println(errors.count())
```

the above snippet would count the number of lines that contain the word ERROR. Is there a simplified function similar to "contains" that would return me the number of occurrences of the word instead?

say the file is in terms of Gigs and i would want to parallalize the effort using spark clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count the instances per line and sum those together:

```
val errorCount = lines.map{line => line.split("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Space}]").filter(_ == "ERROR").size}.reduce(_ + _)
```

Comment: I think that the `map` and `filter` should get pipelined together by Spark, so I'd be surprised if these optimizations reduce memory consumption.  Spark should never end up materializing the full intermediate `lines.map(...)` data set; I think the simple `lines.filter(...).count()` should be pretty efficient.

Comment: @JoshRosen Interesting. Thanks!. Regarding memory consumption, I was refering to the size of the resulting RDD, as RDD[Int] should be << in size than a RDD[String], which could be beneficial assuming the RDD is further used, but `filter(...).count` is indeed pretty simple.

Comment: Tokenizer.scala:39: value collect is not a member of Int
[error] val errors = lines.flatMap{line => if (line.contains("ERROR")) Some(1) else None}.reduce(_ + _).collect ???? but the above code snippets shows a way to count the number of lines containing ERROR rather than number of occurances of ERROR.

Comment: @Siva sorry. The `collect` was not needed. `reduce` is already an action that triggers the RDD computation. - corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks. But how do u get the occurances of word error? than the count of lines?

Comment: @Siva - ouch... that throws me off. The other answer was giving you that and I remember your comment saying that that was not what you were after.

Comment: @Siva - there you go.